# Which command is used for checking if file is not open in linux?

Tags: linux

lsof command is used fot the open files in linux.Which command is used for checking if file is not open.I want to use in my script

my condition is

```
do
        if [[ 'lsof | grep $r_error_file' ]]
        then
                error_text=$error_text$(tail -n +1 $r_error_file | grep 'Error\')
                mv $r_error_file $(dirname ${r_error_file})/BkError/$(filename ${r_error_file})
        fi
done
```

Comment: fuser filename - this shows if there is a process is bound to a file?

Answer (score 1):

Use `fuser` command

```
fuser $filename
if [ $? ne 0 ]
then
    # file is open, Add your code here
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the case where the `lsof` statement is false. There's a useful list of methods for manipulating truth in if statements [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html); but to ruin your fun serarching, you're looking for

```
if [[ ! `lsof | grep $r_error_file` ]]
then
        ...
fi
```

Comment: is it a correct way of using it because i have tried it and having some errors

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you checked you're using backticks (`) instead of apostrophes (') to enclose the lsof / grep pipe?

Comment: using $(  )  instead of ` `  may avoid any confusion there - but why do you put the command between [[ ]], then execute through ` `  ?  looks a bit rube-goldbergish

Comment: Yeah, I agree - I was trying to change as little as possible at once to avoid confusion.